# $0 \lt r \lt s, a \in M$, show $\left\{ x \in M \middle| r \lt d(x,a) \lt s \right\}$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> $M$ is a metric space with metric $d$, given $0 \lt r \lt s, a \in M$, show $A=\{ x \in M : r < d(x,a)
>  < s \}$ is open

I drew a picture and observed the above set looks like a washer. So our goal is to select a $t>0$ such that any point we pick in the open ball $B_t(x)$ where $x \in A$, is within $A$. More specifically, we want to show for a $y \in B_t(x)$, we get $r \lt d(y,a) \lt s$.

For this, this is my choice of $t$:

$t=min\left\{ d(x,a) - r, s - d(x, a) \right\}$

In the picture, it makes perfect sense but I am having trouble deriving the desired result: $r \lt d(y,a) \lt s$

Am I heading in the right direction?

Comment: $x\mapsto d(x,a)$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right direction. The rest follows by triangle inequality: let $d(y,x) <t$. Then  $d(y,a) \leq d(y,x)+d(x,a) <t+d(x,a) \leq s$ and $d(y,a) \geq d(x,a)- d(y,x) >d(x,a)-t \geq r$.

Comment: This is it! I played with the triangle inequality, but where I got confused was I could pick either value for $t$ given the direction of inequality.